# PhpStorm Port 9000 is busy with App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, phpstorm

With only PhpStorm launched I get a `port 9000 is busy` error
using [this cookbook for AppEngine/PhpStorm v9](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/running-debugging-and-uploading-an-application-to-google-app-engine-for-php.html). 
I can reset the port in PhpStorm but how do I reset the port in the app engine php server and is this the correct solution?

```
dps-iMac:~ dp$ sudo lsof -i :9000 
Password: 
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME 
phpstorm 332 dp 288u IPv4 0x1fa7bde7767bedad 0t0 TCP *:cslistener (LISTEN) 
dps-iMac:~ dp$
```

mac os 10.10 phpstorm 9 appengine php v 1.9.24

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "changing the port in PhpStorm" and "changing the port in app engine php server"? It seems that you already have your app running (you wouldn't need to re-run it every time you make a change in the code since the DevServer would pick up changes automatically). Also, this article might be helpful: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Running_the_development_web_server the two parameters that might be helpful are `--port` & `--admin_port` depending on what exactly you mean.

Comment: Well... PhpStorm usually listens to debugger connections on port 9000. You have to stop it if you want to release that port. Enter `CTRL+SHIFT+A` (or in OS X  `SHIFT+COMMAND+A`), type `listen` and press `RETURN` to stop it from listening.

Comment: #3 under [Creating a run configuration fo the type App Engine for PHP]() in the documentation you reference reveals that App Engine's development server uses **port 8080** by default.  As shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/tools/using-local-server), one can use the `--port=8946` option to change this behavior.  This should change the ports used by `dev_appserver.py`.  As for the port being busy, the output you provided indicates that there's already a phpstorm process bound to that port.  If that's not your instance, you may want to kill it and try restarting the server.